# Shadow copy to clone system volume on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, backup, clone, shadow-copy, volume-shadow-service

I am looking for a program that uses shadow copy to copy the contents of a Windows XP system volume that is running.

I.e. I want to clone the system volume with the following snags:
(1) I want to be able to select which files to copy (i.e. not the entire file system)
(2) This is probably implied by (1), but I also have to avoid sector-by-sector copies
(3) I do not want to clone a file system into an image file and restore to a 3rd drive but want to do a filesystem to filesystem copy

All the backup/clone utilities I looked into stumble on one of above points. Any ideas?

Comment: I think on http://superuser.com/ will be happier to answer

Comment: @BlackBear indeed. Voted for migration.

Comment: Thanks BlackBear. I was not aware of superuser.com. I re-posted my question there: http://superuser.com/q/240528/65679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this one: [Hobocopy](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Craig/HoboCopy.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up using ViceVersa which seems to have the same functionality. For further details see the superuser thread on this question.